# База данных sqlite переставляет элементы сама по себе

Tags: python, sqlite

[image: Вот так выглядит база данных]

Вот код:

```
    self.db = "project_db.sqlite"
    self.con = sqlite3.connect(self.db)
    self.cur = self.con.cursor()
    print(list(self.cur.execute("""SELECT id FROM months""").fetchall()))
```

Результат: `[('2022 10',), ('2022 11',), ('2022 9',)]`

Я никак не могу понять почему `('2022 9',)` в конце, а не в начале списка. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: надо задавать `order by`, если хотите получить определенную последовательность. База данных никак не упорядочивает данные при выводе, если явно не требеуют. Во вторых? надо учесть, что  id у вас строка, а не число, поэтому "9" > "1"

Comment: Да, скорее всего тут сортировка по `id` идёт как по строке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, таблицы в базе данных не имеют внутреннего порядка. То есть, простой неупорядоченный запрос может возвращать строки в порядке их внесения, но тут нет никаких гарантий. Если не задан порядок в запросе, база данных возвращает результат в произвольном порядке.

Во-вторых, "база" и "клиент" не одно и то же. Скриншот - SQLiteStudio - это один клиент, а вывод Питона - другой клиент. В обоих случаях запросы не упорядочены, так что нет никаких оснований ожидать одинаковый порядок. И да, если сортировать по id, будет текстовая сортировка, как указано в комментарии.